# UICollectionView horizontal paging shelf

Tags: objective-c, pagination, paging, uicollectionview, horizontal-scrolling

How can I achieve UICollectionView with 1 horizontal row and items in it. Items are "on shelf" which is actually an image that will be at the bottom of collectionView and wont move (will be static). Item image that is in the middle (3 items will be shown at a time) will be a bit bigger than those on sides. Are there any examples for these ?

HELP !! Tnx.

Comment: Is that good for you ? https://github.com/rs/SDSegmentedControl

Comment: actually its just some kind of coverFlow but with collectionView, if you got any of that source code? tnx.

Comment: Check this, then. https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel